# Canvas background doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

In my wpf sofware, I have an image (from a camera) I want to draw in a WPF canvas :

Here is the view :

```
<ScrollViewer Background="{StaticResource HatchBrush}">
            <Canvas Name="CanvasTarget" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin=".5, .5">
            </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Here is the code behind

```
 Messenger.Default.Register<Bitmap>(this, (bmp) =>
 {
       CanvasTarget.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           ImageConverter.Conv8bppTo24(bmp, writeableBitmap);
           CanvasTarget.Background = new ImageBrush(writeableBitmap);
       }));
  });
```

So each time the camera get an image (30Hz), the `CanvaTarget.Dispatcher` is called.

The problem is : No image background is displayed in the canvas, juste hatches from the scrollviewver.

I'm sure my `writeableBitmap` is good and the code is called because, if I replace Canvas by an Image Control and the Background property by the Source property, everything work.

Comment: You should set the Width and Height of the Canvas.

Comment: Yes, was that, thanks !